# Length of shortest hamiltonian path in a circle

Tags: geometry, optimization, upper-lower-bounds, combinatorial-geometry, hamiltonian-path

Let's say I have a circle of radius $r$.

I will place $N$ points inside this circle, and then find the shortest hamiltonian path going through all these points.

[image: illustration]

Of course, I know that this shortest hamiltonain path will be shorter than $2 r\cdot N$

But is there a way to have a better upper-bound ?

Are there research papers about this kind of problem ?

## Edit

The problem can be stated as follow:

let $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C}, |z| \leq 1\}$

$$u_n = \sup_{(p_i)\in D^n}(\min_{\sigma \in S_n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|p_{\sigma(i+1)}-p_{\sigma(i)}|\right))$$

Find the best possible bound for $u_n$

Comment: From above we aren't imposing any routing restrictions, correct? So each node is reachable from any other node and all paths in the plane that stay within the circle are allowed?

Comment: Asymptotically you'd expect $\sqrt{\pi N}$ for a unit circle (up to some constant factor not too far from $1$). I suspect that in general you can't the shortest cycle to be much longer than that, but I don't know by how much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Summary:** For any choice of $N$ points, we can get a Hamiltonian cycle of length at most $8r\sqrt N$. There exist configurations for which we can't do better than about $r \sqrt{\pi N}$.

---

For a bad configuration, chop the circle up into about $\pi k^2$ square tiles of side length $\frac rk$, and put a point in the center of each tile. There is a distance of at least $\frac rk$ between any two points, so any Hamiltonian cycle (which consists of about $\pi k^2$ line segments between the points) must have length at least about $\pi k^2 \cdot \frac rk = \pi kr$. Here, $N \approx \pi k^2$, so $k \approx \sqrt{\frac N \pi}$, and the length $\pi kr$ is about $r\sqrt{\pi N}$.

---

To find a Hamiltonian cycle of length at most $8r \sqrt N$ given $N$ arbitrary points, put the circle into a $2r \times 2r$ square. Chop the square up into $4^k$ square tiles of side length $\frac{2r}{2^k}$, where $k$ is chosen sufficiently large that no two points are inside the same square tile. Then, draw an order-$k$ [Moore curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_curve) through the centers of the square tiles:

[image]

(The image is [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_curve#/media/File:Moore-curve-stages-0-through-5.png).)

Our plan will be to visit the $N$ points in the order that the Moore curve visits the tiles that they're in.

To prove that this does well, we'll need to talk about [Hilbert curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve), since a Moore curve is made up of four of those. The important thing to know about these is that a Hilbert curve of order $k$ takes $4^k - 1$ steps inside a $2^k \times 2^k$ grid, and both the first $4^{k-1}-1$ and the last $4^{k-1}-1$ steps are copies of a Hilbert curve of order $k-1$.

**Lemma 1.** Suppose a Hilbert curve of some order is drawn through the centers of square tiles of side length $\ell$. If $P$ is a point in the $1^{\text{st}}$ square tile, and $Q$ is a point in the $n^{\text{th}}$ tile, then the length $PQ$ is at most $2\ell\sqrt{2n}$.

**Proof.** Choose $j$ such that $4^{j-1} \le n < 4^j$: the least number such that $P$ and $Q$ are both inside an order-$j$ Hilbert curve. That means that they're both contained inside a $2^j \times 2^j$ grid, so the length $PQ$ is at most $2^j \sqrt 2 \cdot \ell$. We get the bound above by bounding $2^{j-1} \le \sqrt n$ (from $4^{j-1} \le n$). $\square$

**Lemma 2.** Now suppose $P$ and $Q$ are (respectively) points in the $p^{\text{th}}$ tile and the $q^{\text{th}}$ tile visited by a Moore curve, where the tiles still have side length $\ell$, and $p<q$. Then the length $PQ$ is at most $4\ell\sqrt{q-p}$.

**Proof.** In between $p$ and $q$, there is a step $r$ where we go from the *end* of a Hilbert curve containing the $p^{\text{th}}$ tile to the *start* of a Hilbert curve containing the $q^{\text{th}}$ tile. Let $R$ be a point on the boundary between those tiles. By Lemma 1 applied twice, $PR \le 2\ell\sqrt{2(r-p)}$ and $RQ \le 2\ell\sqrt{2(q-r)}$. By the triangle inequality, $PQ \le PR + RQ$, and because $x \mapsto \sqrt x$ is concave, the sum is maximized when $r = \frac{p+q}{2}$. In that case, we get $PR + RQ \le 2\ell\sqrt{2 \cdot \frac{q-p}{2}} + 2\ell\sqrt{2 \cdot \frac{q-p}{2}} = 4\ell\sqrt{q-p}$. $\square$

We are ready to find the length of our Hamiltonian cycle. Suppose our points are $P_1, P_2, \dots, P_N$, numbered in the order that the Moore curve visits them. For $1 \le i \le N-1$, let $d_i$ be the the number of steps it takes our Moore curve to go from $P_i$ to $P_{i+1}$; let $d_N$ be the number of steps it takes our Moore curve to go from $P_N$ back to $P_1$, keeping in mind that the Moore curve is closed and symmetric so a form of Lemma 2 still applies. Then the total length $P_1P_2 + \dots + P_N P_1$ is at most $4\ell\sqrt{d_1} + \dots + 4\ell\sqrt{d_N}$, where $\ell = \frac{2r}{2^k}$. By concavity, this sum is maximized when $d_1 = \dots = d_N = \frac{4^k}{N}$, in which case each $\sqrt{d_i}$ is $\frac{2^k}{\sqrt N}$, and their sum is $2^k \sqrt N$. Multiplying by $4\ell$, we get $8r \sqrt N$, as promised.

Comment: I'm writing a bibliography on the subject for a research project in my school. I found some ways to generalize this result, in particular using a space-filling curve that improve your bound to $PQ \leq 2l\sqrt{q-p}$. I was wondering if there exists papers about this I can use in my bibliography ?