# K-Locality of Hilbert curve

Tags: geometric-topology, fractals, combinatorial-geometry

Let $H: [0,1] \to [0,1]\times[0,1]$

be the Hilbert curve (the limit of the family of functions defined on [this page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courbe_de_Hilbert#construction_geometrique) )

This curve is well known for its "good locality propreties"

Meaning that for $(x,y) \in [0,1]\times[0,1]$, If x and y are close, the distance between $H(x)$ and $H(y)$ will be small.

But I would need a more precise measure of how "local" this curve is.

If I'm not mistaken, the answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4517370/length-of-shortest-hamiltonian-path-in-a-circle?noredirect=1#comment9515616_4517370) indicates that

$$\forall x,y \in [0,1], ||H(x)-H(y)|| \leq 4\sqrt{|x-y|}$$

But experimentally, it seems that we can replace the value of 4 by around 2.4 (see [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772109000765))

I'm surprised that nobody proved the value of a smallest constant $K$ such that

$$\forall x,y \in [0,1], ||H(x)-H(y)|| \leq K\sqrt{|x-y|}$$

Is there such a proof ?
If not, is there a "reason" it is so complicated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact we know exactly what this constant is, and it is $\sqrt{6}$

Here is the proof:
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11006-006-0182-8